# Incrementing a variable each time the system boots up

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal

The idea is to initialize a variable and set it to 0. Then create a script that executes on boot and increments that variable by 1 each time the system boots up again.

Sounds simple enough right?

Comment: `(( $(last reboot | wc -l) + 1))`?

Comment: Too many linux systems rotate wtmp, so that's not going to work.

Answer (score 4):

Save the variable to a file, and then read that file every time the system boots.

`` VAR=`cat ~/.foo`

echo $(($VAR + 1 )) > ~/.foo ``

Then edit ~/.foo and enter in 0

You will need to put this inside a script which is called each boot. Every distro is different.

Some use

init.d
upstart
systemd
runinit

http://www.linux.org/threads/init-and-its-alternatives.4876/

Comment: "on boot"  And `.bashrc` will run on *every* shell invocation.

Comment: @RickyBeam I realized that the moments ago and updated the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Some `cron` implementations like the one from the ISC also support running things at boot (upon the cron daemon starting), which allows non-administrators to run things at boot. (`@reboot` in the crontab).

Answer (score 0):

```
touch /var/log/bootcount
echo $[$(</var/log/bootcount)+1] > /var/log/bootcount
```

Add that to `/etc/rc.local` (or equiv for your flavor of linux)

(assuming the system `sh` is `bash`)

Comment: Assuming that `sh` is a `bash` shell is wrong and fails in many cases on all sorts of systems. You can expect `sh` to be a POSIX shell and nothing more. For scripts as simple as this I would highly recommend to stick to POSIX to keep it as portable as possible.

Comment: @Marco, agreed, and that same code is as easy to write with POSIX sh syntax: `echo "$(($(cat /var/log/bootcount) + 1))" > /var/log/bootcount`

Comment: It's tagged "linux", so `bash` is a safe bet.  A true shell(TM) would not have any such fanciness, so one would have to resort to `expr` to get there. (try solaris or aix)

Answer (score 0):

Here I present a shell function which reads the file and increments a value stored in the file. The value is stored in the variable `count`. Finally it writes
the incremented value back to the file.

```
#!/bin/sh

DATAFILEDIR='/var/cache/bootcount'
DATAFILE="$DATAFILEDIR"/count

update_data_file() {
  if [ -w "$DATAFILE" ]; then
    while IFS='=' read key value; do
      case "$key" in
        'count') count="$value" ;;
      esac
    done < "$DATAFILE"
  else if [ ! -d "$DATAFILEDIR" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$DATAFILEDIR"
    count=1
  fi fi

  count=$(($count + 1))
  echo "count=$count" > "$DATAFILE"
}

update_data_file

echo "Boot count is $count"

exit 0
```

You can place the script into `/usr/local/bin` and add it to `/etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a line such as this to a system's `rc.local` should do the trick:

```
$ touch count.txt; CNT=$(<count.txt); echo $(($CNT + 1)) > count.txt
```

Where you want to keep the count file is up to you, simply move `count.txt` or specify it using a variable or a full path. The above takes care of creating the file the first time this gets executed, and will continue to increment the number in that file every time `rc.local` is executed.

**NOTE:** The use of `$(<count.txt)` may present an issue on certain implementations of `sh`, in those situations you may opt to use `$(cat count.txt)` instead.

#### Example

```
$ rm count.txt 
$ touch count.txt; A=$(<count.txt); echo $(($A + 1)) > count.txt
$ cat count.txt 
1

$ touch count.txt; A=$(<count.txt); echo $(($A + 1)) > count.txt
$ touch count.txt; A=$(<count.txt); echo $(($A + 1)) > count.txt
$ touch count.txt; A=$(<count.txt); echo $(($A + 1)) > count.txt
$ cat count.txt 
4
```

Comment: `$(<file)` is not POSIX.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - you're just stating that right?, I didn't see that as a requirement in the Q and it's tagged as Linux so I was assuming standard tools were fair game.

Comment: if you're putting that in a sh file like most startup scripts are, you should use `sh` syntax. Many `sh` interpreters on many Linux based systems don't support that syntax. On unix.SE, if you're suggesting something non-standard, you should point it out. `$(<file)` is not standard either as per the Linux Software Base specification.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas fair enough, changing that command to `$(cat count.txt)` would remove the issue, correct?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I have created this script for use on a Pi.

I waive copyright for all situations where the contents are not charged for :-).

```
#!/bin/bash

# @FIXME DGC 2-Dec-2021 Issue 229
#
# There is a sporadic bug here - and I've no idea what it is.
#
# SOMETIMES - when booting a DX2 ( specifically the 'ventilation' one )
#  the date created by
#     humanDateToNanoseconds="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T.%N")"
#  comes out about five years wrong.
# I have no clue what that is - and it sometimes works fine.


# @file      count-and-time-boot-cycles.sh
#
# @brief     Creates and maintains a file in /boot
#             ( and a duplicate for distaser recovery in /root )
#             currently named 'boot-count.txt' -- but verify theat in the code.
#             which tells us (primarily)
#                Which number boot cycle this is ( from an arbitrary base )
#                The seconds-since-epoch time when the system noticed it had booted.
#                Some other background stuff which was used to create the above, and is is just-for-interest.

# @copyright Copyright Dexdyne Ltd 2021-2021. All Rights Reserved.
#
# @author    DGC

if [ "root" != "$(whoami)" ]
then
    echo "Can only run as root"
    exit 1
fi

#set -x

set -e
set -u

# Get 'uptime' as in /proc/uptime - which on the syswtem I tried output it in units of 10ms.
#  but for 'visual comparability' with other numbers around here,  we pad that to nanseconds.
# 
# Leaves result in the global variable $uptimeSecondsToNanoseconds
#
getUptimeSecondsToNanoseconds()
{
    local uptimeSecondsFloat="$(cat /proc/uptime | cut -d' ' -f 1)"

    local uptimeSecondsWhole="$(echo "${uptimeSecondsFloat}" | cut -d'.' -f 1)"

    local uptimeSecondsPart="0.$( echo "${uptimeSecondsFloat}" | cut -d'.' -f 2)"

    # If we assumed that the decimal part would only and forever be two digits, we could just tack on '00000000' or whatever
    #  but it's good programming not to make such assumptions, so plod our way through a conversion which will always work.

    local uptimeNanosecondsFloat="$(echo "${uptimeSecondsPart} * 1000000000.0" | bc -l)"

    local uptimeNanosecondsInt="$(echo "${uptimeNanosecondsFloat}"  | cut -d'.' -f 1)"

    uptimeSecondsToNanoseconds="${uptimeSecondsWhole}.${uptimeNanosecondsInt}"

    #echo "${uptimeSecondsFloat} ${uptimeSecondsWhole} ${uptimeSecondsPart} ${uptimeNanosecondsFloat} ${uptimeNanosecondsInt} ${uptimeSecondsToNanoseconds}"
}

# Try to do these as simultaneously as possible.
{
    getUptimeSecondsToNanoseconds

    humanDateToNanoseconds="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T.%N")"

    # @FIXME DGC 2-Dec-2021 Issue 229
    #           Some logging to work on the bug noted at the top of the file.
    {
        date
        echo $humanDateToNanoseconds
    } > /root/date-during-boot.txt

    sSEToNanoseconds="$(date +"%s.%N")"
}

#echo "${uptimeSecondsToNanoseconds}"

partitionAPADN="/boot"

directoryRPARN=""                     # Note trailing / is reqd if not empty
countFN="boot-count.txt"

countAPAFN="${partitionAPADN}/${directoryRPARN}${countFN}"

duplicateAPAFN="/root/${directoryRPARN}duplicate-${countFN}"

remountIt=false
if [ "ro" == "$(mount | grep " on ${partitionAPADN}" | grep -o "(r." | grep -o "r.")" ]
then
    remountIt=true 
fi

if $remountIt
then
    #echo "it's ro"

    mount -o remount,rw "${partitionAPADN}"
fi 

trap onExit EXIT

# Arbitrarily decide to leave /boot mounted read-only - that's not really our job

onExit()
{
#    if $remountIt
#    then
        mount -o remount,ro "${partitionAPADN}"
#    fi

#    mount

}

# It is worth noting that the ONLY field from the previous copy of the file which we use
#  is the first one, the number of previous boots.

rescuePrimaryPlease=false
if [ ! -f "${countAPAFN}" ]
then
    if [ ! -f "${duplicateAPAFN}" ]
    then
        echo "Error: Primary and back-up boot count files are both missing. Will set primary to 10000."  >&2

        rescuePrimaryPlease=true
    
        # The secondary will be written to match at the end.
    else
        echo "Problem: Primary boot count file was missing. Will copy the duplicate one to it."  >&2
 
        cp -f "${duplicateAPAFN}" "${countAPAFN}"
    fi
fi

rescueMyPrimary()
{
    {
        echo "$1"
        # Could add dummy entries for the other lines, but it wouldn't have any effect,
        #  we will over-write this below.
    }  > "${countAPAFN}"
}

if $rescuePrimaryPlease
then
    rescueMyPrimary 10000
fi

if [ -f "${countAPAFN}" ]
then
    echo "Primary boot count file exists."  >&2
fi
if [ -f "${duplicateAPAFN}" ]
then
    echo "Back-up boot count file exists."  >&2
fi

# We operate as root, so no need to worry about attributes on that file. 

regularExpressionForAnInteger='^[0-9]+$'

previousCount="$(head -n 1 "${countAPAFN}" | tail -n1 )"

if ! [[ $previousCount =~ $regularExpressionForAnInteger ]]
then
    echo "Error: contents of first line of ${countAPAFN} is not numeric - '$previousCount'" >&2

    previousCount="$(head -n 1 "${duplicateAPAFN}" | tail -n1 )"

    if ! [[ $previousCount =~ $regularExpressionForAnInteger ]]
    then 
        echo "    contents of first line of ${duplicateAPAFN} is ALSO not numeric - will start at 20000 - '$previousCount'" >&2 

        rescueMyPrimary 20000
    else
        echo "        reinstating boot count from ${duplicateAPAFN} as - '$previousCount'" >&2 

        rescueMyPrimary $previousCount
    fi
fi

previousCount="$(head -n 1 "${countAPAFN}" | tail -n1 )"

if ! [[ $previousCount =~ $regularExpressionForAnInteger ]]
then 
    echo "Impossibly we have failed to read/rescue a primary boot count file. quitting."
    exit 1
fi

incrementedCount=$(( ${previousCount} + 1 ))

#previousHumanDateToNanoseconds="$( head -n 2 "${countAPAFN}" | tail -n1 )"
#previousEstimatedBootMomentSSE="$( head -n 3 "${countAPAFN}" | tail -n1 )"
#previousSSEToNanoseconds="$(       head -n 4 "${countAPAFN}" | tail -n1 )"
#previousUptimeSeconds="$(          head -n 5 "${countAPAFN}" | tail -n1 )"

# Subtract from 'the clock seconds-since-epoch' 'the seconds since boot'
#
# That ought to give us the seconds-since-epoch-at last boot moment.
#
# Now this script is only intended to be run once at boot,
#  but logically that estimate should be a constant WHENEVER, and HOWEVER MANY TIMES we run this script
#  ( until the next reboot).
# Contrary to the cockup theory of life, I find that it is indeed remarkably stable and repeatable
#  - I don't see any drift, and it is stable to about 100ms either way.
# Which gives me confidence that we are doing something sensible and reliable.
#
# NOW THERE IS A TIME WHEN THIS WILL FALL APART
#  Any time around a leap-second the clock time will jump a second
#   ( or possibly slide over the previous few hours, - depends on the OS in a way I don't understand )
#   and thye boot ime will shift by a second.
# So if we are 'matching two estimates of the boot time' we should allow a few seconds either way.
#
estimatedBootMomentSSE="$(echo "${sSEToNanoseconds} - ${uptimeSecondsToNanoseconds}" | bc -l)"

# Really we should test for or cast to numeric here. 

{
                                        #          file contents
                                        #   padded for cross-referencing
    echo $incrementedCount              # 27                               Count of boots
    echo ${estimatedBootMomentSSE}      #          1638351910.888602267

    echo $humanDateToNanoseconds        # 2021-12-03 12:03:36.992597796    date to microseconds
    echo $sSEToNanoseconds              #          1638533016.998602267    SSE in microseconds 
    echo ${uptimeSecondsToNanoseconds}  #              181106.110000000
} >  "${countAPAFN}"

# I am not sure of the 'best method' for creating an independent duplicate of the file.
#  You could possibly use 'tee'.
#
# Tentatively I'm going to rewrite it the same way, but independently

{
    echo $incrementedCount
    echo ${estimatedBootMomentSSE}

    echo $humanDateToNanoseconds
    echo $sSEToNanoseconds
    echo ${uptimeSecondsToNanoseconds}
} > "${duplicateAPAFN}"
```