# Increment Daily Config Value

Tags: shell-script

I have a configuration file that contains a lookback value, which I need to increment by +1 each day.

IE: 60, 61, 62 etc....

It doesn't look like `awk` will work because of the formatting of the config file.  I was thinking `sed` could maybe append it to the existing file, but then I will need to set up a counter to work with this operation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Extract the _value_ from the file, increment it, replace it in the file.

Comment: Please show us your actual format. Also show how you create the file etc. We can't help if we don't know what your data look like. Are they comma separated values like in your example?

Comment: See my A to this Q. It shows how you can do the increment part: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113971/incrementing-a-variable-each-time-the-system-boots-up/113992#113992. Making it a cronjob or at job would do the "daily" part.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this file only contains the text

```
IE: 60
```

Do increment it, I would do

```
#!/bin/bash
read label number < filename
echo "$label $((number+1))" > filename
```

or maybe

```
#!/bin/sh
perl -i -pe 's/(\d+)$/ $1 + 1 /e' filename
```

or maybe

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '{$NF++; print}' filename > tmpfile && mv tmpfile filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Intialise the counter file

```
echo "IE: 0 $(( $( date +%s ) /(60*60*24) ))" >cfile
```

cfile stores your label, a *counter* and a *days since epoch* value.

Increment value

```
read label a b <cfile ;incr=$(( $( date +%s ) /(60*60*24) - $b )); echo "$(( $label $a + $incr)) $(( $b + $incr ))" > cfile
```

Display

```
echo "Today's values $( cat cfile )"
```

Storing both a count and a day value since epoch, allows it to be called,

- Multiple times per day only incrementing on first call.
- Several days later, values are incremented correct day difference since last call.